# How to fix org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

I use redis to cache in my boot spring. I have 2 redis servers and a fairly large database. If I use a redis server running the same network, the cache is normal with a total of 619,000 users. But if I use redis running on the docker and setting up a running schedule in the evening it always throws an error message:
**org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out**

I know that this is because redis has to wait for the connection for too long so it will throw an exception if the amount of data is too large. I've done more time out with the constructor but still can not fix it. Information as follows:

```
@Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(redisHostName);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(redisPort);
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPassword(redisPassword);
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }
@Bean
public JedisPool getConfig() {
    JedisPoolConfig config =new JedisPoolConfig();
    JedisPool jedisPool = new JedisPool();
    config.setMaxTotal(100);
    config.setMaxIdle(200);
    config.setMinIdle(50);
    config.setMaxWaitMillis(30000);
    config.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    jedisPool = new JedisPool(config, redisHostName, redisPort,300000,redisPassword);
    return jedisPool;
}
```

So how to overcome the problem. I have set timeout as -1 but if so I think not good in terms of performance

Comment: Can you see more sockets on `TIME_WAIT` state if you execute `netstat` command on web server?

Comment: sorry I do not understand. What do you mean. Execute it on redis?